How can I convert a ffmpeg command to the ffmpeg-python script?
I have a ffmpeg command for converting an audio file from .mpt to .aac and then combining it with a .mp4 video file to create a new video file, as shown below. I would like to convert these commands into a ffmpeg-python script.
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vn -acodec copy a.aac
ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.aac -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem please? Thanks in advance.
I've managed to rewrite the first command in ffmpeg-python (it was easy)
(
    ffmpeg
    .input(a_input)
    .output('a.aac', acodec='aac')
    .global_args('-report')
    .run()
)

However, for the second line, I tried the following script but it does NOT work.
# handles multiple input
video = ffmpeg.input(v_input)
audio = ffmpeg.input('a.aac')

# handles multiple -map flags
output_video = video['v']
output_audio = audio['a']

(
ffmpeg
      .filter([video, audio], 'overlay', 10, 10)
      .output(
           output_video,
           output_audio,
           v_out)
       .run(
           capture_stdout=True,
           capture_stderr=True,
       )
)


python-ffmpeg is only useful if you don't have the cli command. If you do (as in this case), you ought to just call it using subprocess.run and forget about the package.
